# Equivalent permutation representations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

The definition of Equivalent Permutation Representations that is defined in "A course in Theory of Groups" by Derek Robinson

Suppose we have group $G$ has permutation representation on set $X$ and $Y$ so there exist a homomorphisms $\theta_1:G \rightarrow Sym(X)$ and $\theta_2:G \rightarrow Sym(Y)$. Then two representations are equivalent is there exist a bijection $\beta :X \rightarrow Y$ such that for each $i \in X$ and $g \in G$ we have 
$$\beta(i( \theta_1(g))=(\beta(i))\theta_2(g)$$ Is this possible, when same group acting on two different sets are isomorphic then permutation representations of two groups are equivalent? Are there any examples?

Comment: What do you mean by obtaining a permutation from another one? By what process? Conjugation?

Comment: I want to prove actually between two isomorphic groups that their generators are equivalent. So this is why I am looking for how can I prove it and what does this equivalence exactly means here.

Comment: How could you prove something if you do not have a definition of it? You need to properly define equivalent before this question can be answered.

Comment: I found two groups of same index and of same order, but their generators in terms of permutations representations are different, I want to know why we get the same order of the same group of same index but with two different generators? How could it be, is there because of equivalence relations between their generators?

Comment: You have still not defined equivalent, not what you mean by index of a group (which is something that only makes sense when the group is a subgroup of some other group).

Comment: I am afraid I don't know the definition of equivalent. But what I am trying to do is "I have two subgroups of a group of finite index and their index are same for both subgroups, I found the order of these subgroups in GAP is same. So I am looking for their generators, both have two generators x and y, y is the same for both subgroups in permutation representation. but x is different." Now my question is in what conditions their order will be the same, obviously they will be isomorphic. How can I prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by "obviously they will be isomorphic"?

Comment: I mean because their orders are same so I suspect that they might be isomorphic.

Comment: So you have two groups of the same order, and you would like to know if they are isomorphic, given some generators inside another group? Why not just ask GAP if they are isomorphic?

Comment: GAP defines an isomorphic mapping between them. It proves that they are isomorphic.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. You haven't defined what do you mean by "equivalent generators". And of course the same group may be given by many different generating sets. For example, both $\{(1,2),(1,2,3)\}$ and $\{(1,2),(2,3))\}$ generate the same group $S_3$.

Comment: Okay, may be my question was wrong. Can I say, permutation representations of two groups are equivalent? If yes then how could it be?

Comment: This still does not make sense. In the 1st sentence you're saying "representation of two groups are equivalent" - this notion is defined for representations which are homomorphisms $G \mapsto GL(V)$. But you seem to have in mind permutation representations. Secondly, your new edit still does not explain what is your definition of equivalent permutations. You should explain HOW they may be obtained from each other.

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask about permutation representation,s if two groups are isomorphic is there any method to prove that both groups have equivalent permutation representations? I was confused with one paper where author defines equivalent permutations in a symmetric group. http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/multfree.pdf

Comment: I don't know such thing as "equivalent permutation representations", so I can't answer. If you know such definition, please edit the question and tell us. Otherwise this does not lead us any closer to the reply. The paper you mention is on a different topic and does not seem to be relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the definition, it makes sense. However, the definitions refers to two permutation representations of the **same** group. It says explicitly that $\beta(i( \theta_1(g))=(\beta(i))\theta_2(g)$ holds for any $g \in G$. Now, where the second group comes from?

Comment: Here I am taking permutation representations of two subgroups of a group of same index. This is why I asked for their corresponding permutation representations to be equivalent.

Comment: It's a good practice on this site edit the question to clarify all these things. The list of comments is now quite long, you can not force the reader to read all the discussion to figure out what are you asking.

Comment: We still miss a sensible definition of equivalent permutation representations of two different (sub)groups... But perhaps you may consider a simple example of $C_2 \times C_2$ given as $\{(1 2),(3 4)\}$ and $\{(5 6),(7 8)\}$, check if these two permutation representations are equivalent and then see what's going on with its subgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on the following example as Alexander konovalov suggested me in comments, I worked as an example of the Equivalent Permutation Representation.

Let $C_2 \times C_2$ acting on set $X={1,2,3,4}$ and $Y={5,6,7,8}$ we take a homomorphisms $\theta_1:C_2 \times C_2 \rightarrow Sym(X)$ and $\theta_2 \rightarrow Sym(Y)$ as let say $\bar{x_1}=${(1 2),(3 4)} and $\bar{x_2}=$ {(5 6),(7 8)}. We need to define a bijecting mapping $\beta:X \rightarrow Y$ such that it satisfies $$\beta(i(\theta_1(g))=\beta(i)(\theta_2(g))$$ for all $i \in X$ and $g \in C_2 \times C_2$

Let us define $\beta(1)=5$,  $\beta(2)=6$, $\beta(3)=7$ and $\beta(4)=8$ .

$\beta(1(\bar{x_1}))=\beta(2)=6,$
$\beta(1)\bar{x_2}=5 \bar{x_2}=6$  so it holds.

Similarly for $i=3$

$\beta(3(\bar{x_1}))=\beta(4)=8,$
$\beta(3)\bar{x_2}=7 \bar{x_2}=8$ 
it satisfies for all $i \in X$.

With the help of one of my friend David Robertson I found a counter example which is, if we take a group $G=Z_4$ acting on the sets $X={a,b,c,d}$ and $Y={a,b}$ we define a homomorphisms $\theta_1: Z_4 \rightarrow Sym(X)$ by

$1 \rightarrow (a,b,c,d)$

$2 \rightarrow (a,c)(b,d)$

$3 \rightarrow (a,d,c,b)$

$0 \rightarrow ()$

and $\theta_2: Z_4 \rightarrow Sym(Y)$ by

$1 \rightarrow (a,b)$

$2 \rightarrow ()$

$3 \rightarrow (a,b)$

$4 \rightarrow ()$

Again let us suppose a bijection $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ s.that

$$\phi(i(\theta_1(g))=\phi(i)(\theta_2(g))$$ for all $i \in X$ and $g \in Z_4$

take $i=a$ and $g=1$ then

$$\phi(a \theta_1(1))=\phi(b)$$

$$\phi(a)\theta_2(1)=\phi(a)(a,b)$$

$\Longrightarrow$  $\phi(b)=\phi(a)(a,b)$

for $i=b, g=1$
$$\phi(b \theta_1(1))=\phi(c)$$
$$\phi(b) \theta_2(1))=\phi(b)(a,b)$$

$\Longrightarrow$  $\phi(c)=\phi(b)(a,b)$

From the above equations we have

$$\phi(c)=\phi(a)(a,b)(a,b)$$

$\Longrightarrow$ $\phi(c)=\phi(a)$

But $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$
is injective. So this is the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

When two groups are isomorphic, then any isomorphism between the two groups should map each generator from one group to a corresponding generator from the other group. A good conceptual example is that of a vector space - when two vector spaces are isomorphic, there is a bijective correspondence between their basis vectors.

Comment: Caution: the isomorphism maps any set of generators of the first group to a set of generators of the second group.  But there can be other sets of generators of the second group that are **not** the images of the first set under any isomorphism.

Comment: For example, the permutation group $S_3$ can be generated by two $2$-cycles, or by a $3$-cycle and a $2$-cycle.  But there is no isomorphism taking a $2$-cycle to a $3$-cycle.

Comment: I want to know How one permutation can be obtained from other if they are equivalent? Any example.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, the generators of the second group cannot necessarily be mapped to by any generator of the first group. That said, given a set of generators for the second group, this set is the image under the isomorphism of a set of generators for the first group.